# problema com EntityFramework

Tags: sql, entity-framework

vejam o retorno do script, sendo executado diretamento no mysql, pelo sqlYog:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem, quando executo no Visual Studio, o retorno é diferente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado serializado:

```
"TotalMesAMes": [
    {
        "mes": "January",
        "status": "Fechado",
        "valor_negocio": 1500
    },
    {
        "mes": "February",
        "status": "Fechado",
        "valor_negocio": 1260
    },
    {
        "mes": "March",
        "status": "Fechado",
        "valor_negocio": 500
    },
    {
        "mes": "May",
        "status": "Fechado",
        "valor_negocio": 1300
    },
    {
        "mes": "June",
        "status": "Fechado",
        "valor_negocio": 1500
    },
    {
        "mes": "July",
        "status": "Fechado",
        "valor_negocio": 1000
    },
    {
        "mes": "August",
        "status": "Fechado",
        "valor_negocio": 3800
    },
    {
        "mes": "September",
        "status": "Contato",
        "valor_negocio": 0
    },
    {
        "mes": "September",
        "status": "Contato",
        "valor_negocio": 0
    },
    {
        "mes": "September",
        "status": "Contato",
        "valor_negocio": 0
    },
    {
        "mes": "September",
        "status": "Contato",
        "valor_negocio": 0
    },
    {
        "mes": "October",
        "status": "Em andamento",
        "valor_negocio": 5500
    },
    {
        "mes": "October",
        "status": "Em andamento",
        "valor_negocio": 5500
    },
    {
        "mes": "November",
        "status": "Em andamento",
        "valor_negocio": 500
    },
    {
        "mes": "November",
        "status": "Em andamento",
        "valor_negocio": 500
    }
]
```

Estranho, preciso que o retorno seja igual ao executado no sqlyog.
por exemplo, no mes de novembro, esta retornando duas vezes o mesmo valor, mas o correto é novbembro 500 e novembro 400